# Registration during Russian World Cup

Tags: russia, world-cup

As my trip in the World cup comes to an end I just discovered that I needed to register at the cities that I went to.

I've been to: Samara, Kazan, Samara, St. Petersburg, and Moscow.

Unfortunately, since I didn't know, I didn't register in any of the cities. What should I do next? Go to Moscow airport and hope nothing happens? Or should I try to register in the cities that I went to?

I stayed in Airbnb the whole journey and got WhatsApp of the hosts.

Answer (score 2):

Registration **must** be done by your hosts in each place. It's not necessary for you to be in attendance at the time. You should be fine.

([Source](http://russiable.com/registration-visa-russia/))